# FancyProductDesigner cross origin issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am using fancyproductdesigner to decorate the Images....And these image hosted on s3 so when FPD try to generate the deisgned images it was giving cross origin error ..

I already made settings in s3 as recommended by them after that it works on firefox but giving errors on other browsers.

Any Help ??

Comment: What are the settings that you have used? What is the error that you see?

Comment: This is the s3 doc I had followed

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use azure blob storage with fancyproductdesigner. Found out that even though you set the CORS settings correctly on azure, we need to alter a function call in the source of fancyproductdesigner.js in the following way.

```
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, callback, {crossOrigin:'Anonymous'});
```

Please note the addition of third parameter here. This will set the image crossOrigin parameter before the image is loaded into canvas through fabric.js. The canvas will not be tainted anymore.